# Machine Learning encoding categorical data regression potential issue

Tags: python, encoding, data-science, linear-regression, categorical-data

I'm unsure if I can use my encoded data. I used two encoding techniques on my data-set. Mean/Target/Likelihood encoding & Label Encoding. Now the features are on difference scales but I can't just normalize/standardize them. They are categorical. I'm trying to build a linear regression model and yes the target variable is continuous.

- Can I encode pieces of the data in difference ways?
- What could I do if I had continuous predictors?
- How do you find feature importance on categorical data that is either nominal/ordinal?

Comment: Why do you think you need to normalize your data? Is your linear regression algorithm so sensitive to scaling? Why did you encode your variables using different methods? As far as feature importance is concerned then for a linear regression problem these are simply the coefficients for different variables.

Comment: Related to normalizing, I want to select the most importance features. I encoded my data with target encoding because one hot encoding would expand the dimensions of the data too much for my laptop to handle. Some of the categorical features have a hierarchy, so label encoding would be appropriate. Because I encoded features in difference ways that were appropriate, I'm unsure if I should use them like this.